# Python cannot install graphql

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, graphql

I tried to run a python script on my local machine. Apparently this script stops and throws an error with message "no named module graphql". I tried to do `python -m pip install graphql` and it also fails with error message "Don't know how to compile graphql/graphql_ext.pyx". A screenshot of the entire error is shown below.

- The script and commands are ran with the PowerShell
- I use a windows machine
- I use Python version "3.10.7"

[image]

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/graphql/ Installation: `pip install cython`, `pip install graphql`

Comment: On the other hand… [`graphql` 0.0.4](https://pypi.org/project/graphql/0.0.4/) released Dec 7, 2015. Status: Alpha. Are you sure it's useable? Especially with later Python versions?

Comment: There is a fix: https://github.com/nehz/graphql/pull/1 from 2018, still not applied. The package seems to be abandoned, the development stalled.

Comment: There are several newer and updated libraries to work with GraphQL in python. I'd recommend [Graphene](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene), [GraphQL-core](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core) and [Strawberry](https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry).